# Iterate through AWS security group

Tags: boto3

```
for i in configuration_item['configuration']['ipPermissions']:
           if i['FromPort'] == '23':
            compliance_type = 'NON_COMPLIANT'
            annotation = 'SecurityGroup is not compliant:Port 23'
            break
```

The code above works if there is ONLY one rule but fails for multiple rules. So how do I iterate through all the rules ( checking ports/ipRanges etc )

Comment: how `configuration_item` is defined?

Comment: It's part of a Lambda which AWS config invokes.
def lambda_handler(event, context):

    invoking_event = json.loads(event['invokingEvent'])
    configuration_item = invoking_event["configurationItem"]
    evaluation = evaluate_compliance(configuration_item)

Comment: " fails for multiple rules" is not very specific. Any error messages?

Comment: Key error. If there are multiple "ToPort" , it says Invalid key ToPort. e.g. if I have rule for port 22/23 it does not work. If only one port, no issues.

Comment: Your code does not show any `ToPort` use. I  think it would be better if you provided complete code with valid example of `event`.

Comment: I meant, update the question with proper code formatting.

Comment: Sorry. Just started posting here. Let me see.

Comment: So, even if I change the "FromPort" to "ToPort", the above code works if there is a single rule ( regardless of port ). If there are rules "ToPort" 22 , 23,80 ( anything > 1 ), it complains of key error.

Answer (score 1):

This will iterate through and get all the sgs and permissions.

You can use this to filter for what you are looking for.

```
import boto3
    ec2 = boto3.client('ec2',region_name='us-west-1')
    response = ec2.describe_security_groups()
    for i in response['SecurityGroups']:
       print "Security Group Name: "+i['GroupName']
       print "the Egress rules are as follows: "
       for j in i['IpPermissionsEgress']:
           print "IP Protocol: "+j['IpProtocol']
           for k in j['IpRanges']:
              print "IP Ranges: "+k['CidrIp']
       print "The Ingress rules are as follows: "
       for j in i['IpPermissions']:
           print "IP Protocol: "+j['IpProtocol']
           try:
              print "PORT: "+str(j['FromPort'])
              for k in j['IpRanges']:
                  print "IP Ranges: "+k['CidrIp']
           except Exception:
              print "No value for ports and ip ranges available for this security group"
              continue
```